# ROS2 with Eclipse

Tags: ros2, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even after configuring Eclipse for ROS2 ([here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Building-ROS-2-on-Linux-with-Eclipse-Oxygen)), I cannot resolve the ROS2 related commands in Eclipse.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292011/ros2-with-eclipse/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-28**:
What does `We enter environment variables. We can get the vars, if we run "env > /tmp/out", then source the ROS 2 local_setup.bash, then "env > /tmp/out1" and "diff /tmp/out /tmp/out1".`  means ? where to run `env>/tmp/out`

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-28**:
Now while building the project i get an error : `OSError: Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link`. Could it be because it set the path variables not correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You run these commands like "env>/tmp/out" on a bash console. If you only run "env" on bash console you will see the environment of this bash console, If you then source the local_setup.bash on the same bash console and then run "env" on this bash console again, you will see that new environment vars are added and others are manipulated. You need to add these environment vars to eclipse.

"cannot resolve ros2 related commands" does mean , cannot resolve functions and methods and so on. You need to check https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Eclipse-Oxygen-with-ROS-2-and-rviz2#Debugging_with_eclipse   "eclipse indexer" section

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2018-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0